# NullPointerException while executing Post Request using RetroFit2

Tags: android, post, nullpointerexception, retrofit2

I have a service which receives parameters and returning a json in response. The response json is as given below

```
{
    "status": 0,
    "message": "You are successfully registered",
    "user": [
        {
            "name": "Rajiv",
            "dob": "10/12/1988",
            "gender": 1,
            "qualification": "1",
            "streams": "1",
            "contactno": "3423234333",
            "email": "rajiv88@gmail.com",
            "password": "testpass",
            "api_key": "29b9522d1bd23161db5aba89933a6015",
            "profilepic": "NA",
            "phverified": 0,
            "emverified": 0,
            "active": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

I have written the interface as given below :

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("v20/register")
Call<RegisterResponse> insertUser(
        @Field("name_of_user") String name,
        @Field("dob") String dob,
        @Field("gender") int gender,
        @Field("qualification") String qualification,
        @Field("streams") String streams,
        @Field("contactno") String contactno,
        @Field("email") String email,
        @Field("password") String password);
```

The Register Response Class is as given below

```
import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import com.sbs.data.User;

public class RegisterResponse {

    @SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    private Integer status;
    @SerializedName("message")
    @Expose
    private String message;
    @SerializedName("user")
    @Expose
    private List<User> user = null;

    public Integer getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Integer status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public List<User> getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(List<User> user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

}
```

I called the service function as follows :

```
Call<RegisterResponse> call=jobApiService.insertUser(edName.getText().toString(),
                edDob.getText().toString(),
                spnGender.getSelectedItemPosition()+1,
                categoryIDString, subCategoryIDString, txtPhone.getText().toString(), edmail.getText().toString(),
                edpass.getText().toString());
        call.enqueue(new Callback<RegisterResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<RegisterResponse> call, Response<RegisterResponse> response) {

                Log.d("hj", "Number of users received: " + response.body().getMessage());

            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<RegisterResponse> call, Throwable throwable) {
                Log.d("hj", "Error");

            }
        });
```

But I am receiving

```
NullPointerException
```

When this statment

Log.d("hj", "Number of users received: " + response.body().getMessage());

executes.

Can anybody suggest a solution

Comment: can you share complete **stacktrace error**?

Comment: you have to check if the call was Successful,  using response.isSuccessful() before trying to read the response value... onResponse, will be called if there is a server response, this response may be a failure code like 404 ou 500!

Comment: Replace your log line with this  Log.d("hj", "Number of users received: " + response.getMessage()); 
remove body()

Comment: @Vijendrapatidar I am getting this response message as "Bad Request"

Comment: So please first try in postman then apply in your code we have send data in three types "form-data" "x-www-form-urlencoded" "raw"
backend developer what kind of data required check in postman or ask him.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you are getting a response from the remote server. if its null then test your api separately using postman or any other tool. If it works then check your request code.

```
public void onResponse(Call<RegisterResponse> call, Response<RegisterResponse> response) {

    if(resonse.body != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(response.body().getMessage())){
        Log.d("hj", "Number of users received: " + response.body().getMessage());
    } else {
        Log.d("hj", "response received is null, but why??");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing initializer null for List  user.

Answer (score 0):

We have send data in like this

Body type -> **Raw** like this 
  for this type we have send data in a model

```
@POST("user")
fun userInsert(@Body userModel: UserRequestModel): Observable<Response>

{
  "email": "abcd@abcd.com",
  "password": "123123"
}
```

Body type -> **x-www-form-urlencoded** like this

```
@POST("user")
 fun userInsert(@Body userHm:  HashMap<String,String>): Observable<Response>

 Hasmap <String, String> hm =new Hasmap<>()
 hm.put("Key", value)
```

Body type -> **form-data**
 this type is required for multipart